# 2 jQuery Scripts conflict !

Tags: jquery, scripting, dynamic, conflict

I used two 2 jquery (plugins) scripts, one for navigation and one for dynamic content.

1. http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-3/
2. http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/

They work fine alone but not together. I tired to switch the scripts, when I change the order of scripts in index.html, the scripts which is in last starts working, like it is ignoring the first one. For example in this order the menu is working:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/dynamicpage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in this order, the dynamic content is working:

```
<script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/dynamicpage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is dynamicpage.js :

```
$(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#wrapper"),
        baseHeight   = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

})(jQuery);
```

And this is menu.js :

```
jQuery.fn.initMenu = function() {  
    return this.each(function(){

        var theMenu = $(this).get(0);
        $('.acitem', this).hide();
        $('li.expand > .acitem', this).show();
        $('li.expand > .acitem', this).prev().addClass('active');
        $('li a', this).click(
            function(e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                var theElement = $(this).next();
                var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                if($(parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
                    if(theElement[0] === undefined) {
                        window.location.href = this.href;
                    }
                    $(theElement).slideToggle('normal', function() {
                        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                            $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                        }    
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && theElement.is(':visible')) {
                        if($(parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
                            $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', 
                            function() {
                                $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                            }
                        );
                        return false;  
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && !theElement.is(':visible')) {         
                    $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', function() {
                        $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                    });
                    theElement.slideDown('normal', function() {
                        $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    );
});
};

$(document).ready(function() {$('.menu').initMenu();});
```

Please help, I'll be really thankful !

P.S. this is the current order of scripts in which only dynamic content is working, menu is not working:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/dynamicpage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: try to contact their developers, maybe they already faced this problem ever before. hard to tell if one doesn't know whole code of plugins or never faced the same as you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that both scripts are binding an event on the `<a>` tags within `<nav>` and `.menu` (respectively), and both of them `return false` at the end of the click function(). The return false would prevent the event to propagate and be executed by the other script...

So in effect, the click function from last script you load that adds a click binding on those `a` tags gets executed first, return false and thus prevents the first script's binding to be called.

If that's the problem, modifying the plugins to have the click functions return true and calling event.preventDefault() instead might do the trick (not 100% sure on this one)

**EDIT**

It's hard to fix without digging into what exactly this is all supposed to do but try replacing this in dynamicpage.js

```
$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });
```

with this

```
$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        e.preventDefault()
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried the changes but it doesn't work. I've noticed one more thing, when I open in IE, it shows blank, no content no menu just the background image. It is just a simple site with menu on left and content on right. The idea is to make the website dynamic, which means when someone clicks on a menu item, the content should load without page refresh. For that I used a plugin dynamicpage.js and for menu I use menu.js plugin. These both plugins work fine alone but not together. Please email me at kashife at yahoo dot com so that I could send you the local site folder.